# HTML area tag shape="default" does not work in IE

Tags: html, tags, area

I tried adding

`<area shape="default" href="venus.htm">`

in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap

remember to remove all other areas

it does not work in IE

my use case is i want to make the whole image clickable without using anchor tag

**UPDATE**

as @Jon Combe answered I updated code and tested 
onclick will not work if image is already wrapped with an anchor tag

```
<a href="xyz.com">
<img src="Chrysanthemum.jpg" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" onclick="self.location.href='venus.htm';event.stopPropagation();" >
</a>
```

Can inner image element eat up click element, not passing to outer elements?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few pages on the web documenting that shape="default" doesn't work when using IE.

Two options, spring to mind:

1. If you know the size of your image, keep using an imagemap, but use the `shape="rect"` attribute instead and have the coords equal the size of the image, i.e. for a picture 145x126 pixels, use `coords="0,0,145,126"`
2. Don't use an imagemap at all and put an `onclick` attribute on the image itself, e.g. `<img src="myimage.jpg" onclick="self.location.href='venus.htm'">`

Comment: `<a href="xyz.com">
<img src="Chrysanthemum.jpg" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" onclick="self.location.href='venus.htm';event.stopPropagation();" >
</a>` it does not works if image is already wrapped with anchor tag

Comment: Your post specifically stated you did not want there to be an anchor tag. I don't understand why you have added one (which of course will break my answer)

Comment: thats correct, it is some thing like this - I dont want to add a hyperlink by myself. I am trying to change href of an image on others website